# How to do Search in Symfony OneToMany?

Tags: php, symfony, dql, symfony5

I have following relationship

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $image_name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Tags::class, mappedBy="image",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $tags;
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $tag_name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Image::class, inversedBy="tags")
 */
private $imageStock;
```

In my search form when I need to do a searching I must get the image which is matched to search inputs. The Search is done either by Image Name or Tag Name.
I have following table.

Image

```
 id|image_name
  1|Spider Man
```

Tags

```
 id|tag_name  |image_id
  1|Spider Man|1
  2|Movie     |1
  3|Xyz       |1
```

I'm confused how to do query in Repository.

This is what I have tried:

```
       $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('ca1')
    ->add('select', 'c, i')
    ->add('from', 'App:Image c')
    ->leftJoin('c.tags', 'i')
    ->where('c.image_name = :search_name')
    ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
    ->setParameters([
        'search_name' => "%$search_name%",
    ])
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I suggest you to first write your query as a pure sql query (test if it works) and then try to build it with the query builder. If you can properly write your sql query but can't find out how to create your sql query with the QueryBuilder, please edit your question and add the pure sql query.

Answer (score 1):

If in image repository it would be something like this:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.tags', 'i')
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
        ;

    return $qb
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->like('c.image_name', ':search_name'),
                $qb->expr()->like('i.tag_name', ':search_name'),
            )
        )
            ->setParameter('search_name', "%$search_name%")
        ->getResult()
        ;
```

And it is better to follow camelCase for your parameters like `$imageName` and `$tagName`, and so on;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `LIKE` instead of `=`:

```php
/** @var Image[] $images */
$images = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Image::class, 'image')
    ->select('image')
    ->leftJoin('image.tags', 'imtag')
    ->addSelect('imtag') // Optional, use only if you want to access tags.
    ->where('image.image_name LIKE :search_name')
    ->orWhere('imtag.tag_name LIKE :search_name')
    ->setParameter('search_name', "%$search_name%")
    ->orderBy('image.id', 'ASC')
    ->getResult()
;
```

---

- Doctrine query builder is parsed to `DQL`, you can retrieve the `DQL` via `getDQL()` on the query builder.
- You can view the executed `SQL` query in the Symfony profiler in the `Doctrine` section.
- As mentioned in the comment, at first it is easier to write `SQL` and then `DQL`.